# imagemagick convert command not working correctly in php script but does work from command line

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

A system call to convert in php worked for years but quit working early this year.  All commands that I am using work correctly if issued from the command line using Putty.

A test php file I created to debug this is

```
<?  
$string = "convert  -verbose -resize 200x200  \"startline/main_menu.png\" \"image/temp222_main_menu.png\" ";
passthru($string);
?>

<IMG SRC='image/temp222_main_menu.png '  alt='main_menu'>
```

The output file is not created.  I get this response

```
startline/main_menu.png PNG 600x1024 600x1024+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 92.1KB 0.020u 0:00.020
```

If I replace my string with this

```
$string = "convert  -version -resize 200x200  \"startline/main_menu.png\" \"image/temp222_main_menu.png\" ";
```

The output file is created but not resized.

I get this response:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2012-04-26 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC Features: OpenMP
```

The interesting thing is that this worked from 2008 until early this year.  That may have been when I switched to PHP5 and a new server, not sure.  This is running at 1and1.com

Tech support at 1and1 said the problem was the outfile didn't exist and closed the case.  That was not very helpful.

I am wondering if there is something I need to put in my php.ini file or something.

---

I also tried this:
    
    exec("/usr/bin/convert -resize 200x200  image/temp222_main_menu.png");
    ?>

Just a note.  I put the verbose in so that I could be sure that I was in fact running the program, that there was some output returned.  It also shows that it is loading the correct file.  That is also why I used passthru instead of exec or system.  This is just a test script.  The script I was using before it broke did not use passthru but had too much going on to post.  The key is that the string that is executed does not work in php but does work on the command line so it is correct.

Comment: Which operating system is your PHP running on?

Comment: PHP under Linux.  Note that all these scrips ran for 4 years.  Something changed in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went through this exact same problem. The really odd thing I noticed is that if the image happened to be the exact size I was trying to resize to, then it worked. Anywawy, It seems to be an issue with memory usage and can be fixed by a config setting in PHP. After browsing other forums I found this and it fixed it.

Place this line at the top of your PHP script that calls imagemagick:

```
putenv("MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1");
```

Comment: Forgot to mention... I encountered this using 1and1 shared hosting.

Comment: Your welcome :) This drove me crazy for a few days so figured I should share the answer and save others from suffering. If you are one of those people that isn't just satisfied with it working and want to understand the solution, here is the link to the guy that found the solution and a good explanation (see comment #6). [http://drupal.org/node/1493574](http://drupal.org/node/1493574)

Answer (score 2):

You should try these steps to debug the problem.

**First,** verify if the setup works at all, by providing full paths to all filenames and commands:

```
<?php  
exec("which convert");
?>

<?php  
exec("/path/to/convert  /path/to/a.png  -resize 200x200  /tmp/a200x200.png");
?>
```

(Obviously, you'll have to adapt paths to your situation.)

**Then,** check if the user account your PHP is running under has even the privilege to write to your target directory:

```
<?php  
exec("pwd");
exec("touch $(pwd)/image/temp222_main_menu.png");
?>
```

---

I would change your code to this to get it working at all:

```
<?php  
exec("/usr/bin/convert -resize 200x200  image/temp222_main_menu.png");
?>

<IMG SRC='image/temp222_main_menu.png'  alt='main_menu'>
```

**Note...**

1. ...I removed the `-verbose` part (it only generates an additional line on *stderr* `startline/main_menu.png PNG 600x1024 600x1024+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 92.1KB 0.020u 0:00.020` and is probably the cause why the convert command never completes the conversion.
2. ...I didn't use your `-version` modification, because it doesn't make sense in your context (and it also leads to skipping the `-resize` part).
3. ...I removed a space in your `<IMG SRC=....` line.
4. ...I switched to `exec(...)`

If you insist to add some noise to *stderr* output, you can try to add the `-monitor` parameter instead of the `-verbose`...

Comment: Thank you for replying   which convert -> /use/bin/convert  I can write in that file directory and do so all the time.  Using the path on the convert exec changes nothing.

Comment: See edit to my post.  I tried the changed code although I added some quotes to get it to run but got the same non output.

Comment: <? 
$string = "convert   -resize 200x200  \"startline/main_menu.png\" \"image/temp222_main_menu.png\" ";
exec($string);
echo "<hr>$string<hr>";
?>
<IMG SRC='image/temp222_main_menu.png ' alt='main_menu'>

Comment: Sorry, this is *not* what I recommended!

Comment: what you recommended didn't run as the quotes were missing.  It generated a php error message so I fixed that.  If I take out the string variable and enter the string directly into the exec command I get the same result.  Here is the error from what you posted:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ')' in /homepages/46/d251035929/htdocs/l36/temp222.php on line 2

Comment: The main point of my recommendation was to test *first* with an absolute path for the output: `/tmp/a200x200.png` to a directory that is very much likely to be writeable for anyone. This test would establish if it is maybe a permission problem... But you continued to test with relative paths, about which you don't know where they lead to...